# Make a packer variable non-required

Tags: json, packer

Is there a way to create a non-required packer variable?

let's say that I have the following:

```
{
  "variables": {
    "provisioner": null
  },
```

I receive the following output: `required variable not set: provisioner`

and I just need to be able to leave it undefined..

Background: I am creating a single packer json that can deploy any image with a single python script that generates a variables.json file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set provisioner to empty string instead of null. If you set it to null it will force it to be a required variable.

```
{
    "variables": {
        "provisioner": ""
    }
}
```

This is outlined in the documentation [here](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/user-variables.html#usage).

"If the default value is null, then the user variable will be required. This means that the user must specify a value for this variable or template validation will fail."